# Google Analytics Events Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am struggling to get the following Google Analytics code to call back. Upon submitting the form, the page refreshes and nothing happens. I am new to javascript and at a bit of a loss as to why the events are not being created and why the callbacks don't return. Assistance would be greatly appreciated as I'm running out of ideas.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-redacted for SO-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon');
</script>

<script>
var formSubmitted = false;
  function submitForm() {
    if (!formSubmitted) {
      formSubmitted = true;
      alert("called back");
      $("#test").submit();
    }
  }
 $("#signUpFree").click(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault;
    setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);
    ga('send', 'event', { 
     eventCategory: 'registration', 
     eventAction: 'submit',
     eventLabel: 'NewFreeUser',
     eventValue: 1,
     hitCallback:submitForm});
    });

</script>

<form action="GATest.html" method ="post" id="test">
  <input type="text" name="FName"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="signUpFree" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you try to define your click handler before the button exists on the page... At the very least, you should move your form above the script tag that contains the $("#signUpFree").click handler.

But a better approach is to use jquery's "onload" handler to attach your handlers only when the page is ready to accept them:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() { // <== this is the onload handler; code in here will only run once the DOM (or page) is ready
        var formSubmitted = false;
        ....
    });
})(jQuery); // good practice to scope your "$" variable
```

And that should do it! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks MacPrawn, the code now runs and the call back alert displays, but when checking the Google Tag Assistant in Chrome it says only the page view tag ran and I don't see anything about the registration event.

Comment: Hmmm - seems to work for me... Do you see the call in your browser? Using the network inspector, look for "collect" in the list of urls and there should be one for the pageview, and one for the event.

If you see both, then your browser did its job and sent both. If GA doesn't list the event, either your event's being ignored for some reason, or it never reached GA. (unlikely)

Comment: Hi MacPrawn, I've posted a screenshot so you can see the network calls. It appears there is a 2nd collect event which vanishes after I close the alert. However it seems to be very small and I don't see anything in the Tag Assistant for this event.

http://i68.tinypic.com/30jqs5s.png

Comment: Got it - so the call is definitely sent to GA, then. If you wanted to inspect that call, in the network inspector, check the "Preserve log" checkbox before you click your button; that won't clear the network logs when the new page reloads.

Alternatively, you could also temporarily comment-out the form submission after your alert pops-up.

Have you checked in GA directly, to see if the events are being logged or not?

Comment: Apologies for the late response; thought you might appreciate some closure. It was taking >24 hours for the data to show up in the Goal section of GA. Your solution fixed it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hey - thank you for this! Yes, those random delays can be quite unnerving sometimes... Very happy it's working now, though!